# React How to clear all input values from infinite inputs list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm coding a infinite inputs component to add bill items in a page, so the user can add how many items row as he wants. But now I have a crucial problem, when I click on "cancel" button for clean all the inputs and show just 1 row of items I show the previous state of this first row. How can I clear all the inputs and then show the placeholder in the first row of items? Thanks

PrincipalComponent.tsx:

```
type BillingManualProps = LinkStateProps & LinkDispatchProps;

const BillingManual: React.FC<BillingManualProps> = ({...}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <section className="entity__main-container">
        <div className="billing-manual-items-to-bill">
          <h2 className="billing-title-row">Indique los ítems a facturar:</h2>
          <BillingItems
            selectedShipper={selectedShipper}
            selectedShipperSettings={selectedShipperSettings}
            billItems={billItems}
            setOpenBillItem={setOpenBillItem}
            setUpdateBillItem={setUpdateBillItem}
            setNewBillItem={setNewBillItem}
            setRemoveBillItem={setRemoveBillItem}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="billing-manual-shadow">
          {billItems && (
            <IonLabel
              className="shipper_document_add_new_document button-border"
              onClick={() => setNewBillItem()}
            >
              + NEW ITEM
            </IonLabel>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="billing-manual__buttonsGroup">
          <GalaxyButton
            color="medium"
            className="GalaxyButton"
            onClick={() => {
              resetPropsFn();
            }}
          >
            CANCEL
          </GalaxyButton>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};
```

resetProps action:

```
export const resetPropsFn = () => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch(billingManualSlice.actions.resetPropsFn());
  };
};
```

resetProps Slice:

```
resetPropsFn: (state) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        selectedShipper: null,
        selectedShipperSettings: null,
        billItems: [
          {
            item: null,
            amount: null,
          },
        ],
      };
    },
```

Billin child component:

```
<div className="billing-manual-scroll">
      {!!billItems &&
        billItems.map((document, id) => {
          return (
            <div key={id} className="billing-manual-items-container">
              <IonRow className="input-delete-container" key={id}>

                <IonCol className="billing-manual-column" size="6">
                  <IonItem style={{ marginTop: 4 }}>
                    <IonLabel color="primary" position={'stacked'}>
                      Ítem {id + 1}*
                    </IonLabel>
                    <TextField
                      name={'item'}
                      defaultValue={null}
                      id="billing-item-input"
                      variant="standard"
                      fullWidth={true}
                      disabled={
                        !(!!selectedShipper && !!selectedShipperSettings)
                      }
                      placeholder={'Indique el ítem a facturar'}
                      value={document.item ? document.item : null}
                      onChange={(event: any) => {
                        setUpdateBillItem(
                          id,
                          ValuesType.ITEM,
                          event.target.value
                        );
                      }}
                    />
                  </IonItem>
                </IonCol>
                <IonCol className="billing-manual-column" size="6">
                  <IonItem style={{ marginTop: 4 }}>
                    <IonLabel color="primary" position={'stacked'}>
                      Monto*
                    </IonLabel>
                    <TextField
                      name={'amount'}
                      defaultValue={null}
                      style={{ backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5' }}
                      fullWidth={true}
                      type={'number'}
                      disabled={
                        !(!!selectedShipper && !!selectedShipperSettings)
                      }
                      placeholder={'0.00'}
                      value={
                        !!selectedShipper && !!selectedShipperSettings
                          ? document.amount
                          : null
                      }
                      onChange={(event: any) => {
                        setUpdateBillItem(
                          id,
                          ValuesType.AMOUNT,
                          event.target.value
                        );
                      }}
                      InputProps={{
                        type: 'search',
                        startAdornment: (
                          <InputAdornment position="start">
                            {' '}
                            <AttachMoney fontSize={'small'} />
                          </InputAdornment>
                        ),
                      }}
                    />
                  </IonItem>
                </IonCol>
              </IonRow>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set all the input states/hooks to empty string after completing the desired action

Comment: Yes, i coded it in the store, set the first row of my object array as null but The input shows the previous state...